# C# No data exists for the row/column issue

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access database. When I try to execute code, it's getting "No data exists for the row/column". I executed the sql code in Microsoft Access and it worked.

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM (adet) AS gToplam from stok_isl WHERE stok_id = @veri and tur = 'GİRİŞ'", conn);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veri", combo);
OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();


OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT SUM (adet) AS cToplam from stok_isl WHERE stok_id = @veri and  tur = 'ÇIKIŞ'", conn);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@veri", combo);
OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();


Sonuc = Convert.ToDouble(dr1["gToplam"]) - Convert.ToDouble(dr2["cToplam"]);

MessageBox.Show(Sonuc.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are retrieving just one number, [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar.aspx) seems to be a better option for you:

```
...
double gToplam = (double)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
...
double cToplam = (double)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

Sonuc = gToplam - cToplam;
```

However you still can get by with `ExecuteReader` of course. The problem is that you did not invoke `Read` (see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca.aspx) for example of usage) method to read first row of the resulting set:

```
...
OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
dr1.Read();
...
OleDbDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
dr2.Read();
```

Please note that both these code samples do not check for the case when query returns empty results.